# Package upgrade on Ubuntu raid server and grub setup issue

Tags: raid, ubuntu-10.10, grub2, upgrade

I have remote Ubuntu 10.10 server running on raid system. I did package upgrade yesterday night for security reasons. During the upgrade, grub installation screen appeared and asked me which partition I wanted to install grub. Options are sda,sdb,md1 and md2. I decide to install them on both sda and sdb partitions.

I wondering, was I make true decision? If machine get reboot is it can be boot up safely?

You can find fdisk output and fstab mount points below:

Fstab:

```
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts gid=5,mode=620 0 0
/dev/md0 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/md1 /boot ext3 defaults 0 0
/dev/md2 / ext3 defaults 0 0
```

Fdisk:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00029bb5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1         262     2102562   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2             263         295      265072+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3             296       91201   730202445   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md0: 2152 MB, 2152923136 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 525616 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md1: 271 MB, 271319040 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 66240 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md2: 747.7 GB, 747727224832 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 182550592 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md2 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdb: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00088969

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1         262     2102562   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2             263         295      265072+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3             296       91201   730202445   fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as your raids are in the sda and sdb,  especially were /boot is, you will not have any problem to reboot the system and it will work since you have did a shoutgun approach and installed grub on all your disks and grub is automatically sniff your drives to see where the /boot is.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get your words enough. Can you explain more specific?

Comment: when you install grub it check you system and build automaticly the files it needs for the system to reboot correctly, now your problem is what is the the disk it should be in , and my answer is since you have installed it on all of your disk it doesn't matter where is it and you could reboot your system. the sda and sdb aren't partitions but disks and grub going to be at the MBR of both.